# How can I calculate a confidence interval for the mean based on non-independent data?

Tags: confidence-interval, independence

In Chemical industrial, samples are often analyzed multiple times, e.g. 5 samples and each was analyzed 2 times with 10 data points in total.  What would be the confidence interval for the mean estimated from these data?  The degrees of freedom is somewhere from 4 to 10 depending on the correlation between repeats.

Comment: The answer will depend on 1) the distribution you expect for the concentration of each sample (if you sample from a slightly heterogeneous solution), and on 2) the distribution of the errors of the analysis method. I assume there are usual hypothesis for this, like for 2) centered gaussian error, are you aware of this?

Comment: Let's assume 2), i.e. the measurement error follows gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1):

My question (in the comments) was mainly on the variation between samples. Is it normal? It is unclear to me, I suspect that for small concentrations it is not the good model. Anyway, let’s assume it is normal.

Let’s formalize a little bit. If $c$ is the true concentration, the concentration of sample $i$ is $C_i = c + E_i$ where $E_i \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_s^2)$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

Each sample is analyzed $m$ times ($m=2$ in your case), and the measurement error is gaussian: this leads to measures $X_{ij} = c + E_i + F_{ij}$ where $F_{ij} \sim \mathcal N(0, \sigma_m^2)$ for $j=1,\dots,m$. All errors $E_i$ and $F_{ij}$ are independent.

Let’s call $Y_i$ the mean of the $m$ measures of sample $i$:
$$Y_i = {1\over m} \sum_{j=1}^m X_{ij}.$$
The distribution of $Y_i$ is $\mathcal N\left(c, \sigma_1^2\right)$ where $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma^2_s + {1\over m} \sigma^2_m$.

Now we are in a perfectly classical situation. All $Y_i$ are independent, with the same normal distribution. The unknown concentration $c$ will be estimated by the sample mean $\hat c = {1\over n} \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$. The variance $\sigma_1^2$ will be estimated as usual by $s_1^2 = {1\over n-1}\sum_i (Y_i - \hat c)^2$.

A confidence interval of level $1-\alpha$ is given by
$$ \hat c \pm t^{n-1}_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt{ {s_1^2 \over n} },$$
where $t^{n-1}_{1-\alpha/2}$ is the $1-\alpha/2$-th quantile of the distribition $t(n-1)$.

The answer to your question is that there are $n-1$ df, **but** the estimation of variance is not to be done as if all measures were independent. You have to follow this two steps procedure:

1. compute the means of all $m$ measures of each sample;
2. treat them as $n$ independent measures.

**Edit: about the data of GJ Hahn (cf comments)**

If you have two samples, each analysed 5 or more times, leading to average measures of 50 and 60, you can compute a 90% confidence interval with
$$\begin{align*} & \hat c \pm t^{1}_{0.95} \sqrt{ {s_1^2 \over 2} }\\
=& 55 \pm 6.31 \sqrt{ {50\over 2}}\\
=& [23.4 \,;\, 86.6]
\end{align*}$$

Alternatively, if you are only interested in a lower bound of the concentration (which is Hahn question, does the average exceed 40 ?), you can say that $[23.4,+\infty)$ is a 95% one-side confidence interval.

Comment: When applying your method to the following example with n=2 and m-5.  Sample 1: avg=50 (50,51,49,51,49) and Sample 2: avg=60 (60,61,59,60,60). The 95% CI based on (50,60) is (-8,118) with df=1.  The example is taken from "Beware of nonindependent observations" by Gerald Hahn (1977 Chemical Technology).  The 95% CI from the artcile is (23,87).

Comment: @AldousWong Are you suggesting that the method is wrong? What is the method used by Gerald Hahn?

Comment: Note that this is 2 samples each analyzed 5 times, not 5 samples each analyzed 2 times...

Comment: Hahn's article does not show calculation method.  Based on the references, I think he is using Variance Component and some why adjusting the df.  Working backward from (23,87) suggests the df > 1 but less than 2. Elvis, I am interested the right method to handle this type of data which are very common in process industries.

Comment: @AldousWong  Some additionnal hypotheses are needed that I can't figure out. Or there's a misprint in the paper... Can you put it in some place where we can download it?

Comment: Elvis, please send email to aldous.g.wong@esso.ca.  We can discuss further.  I really appreciate your help.